# MYSQL merge wp_posts and wp_postmeta together

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, join

Hello i realise this question has been asked and i could not solve the issue with the answers.

I have built a CMS with a course i am on, i have a live website which is WordPress and wish to move all the posts over to my new CMS, in my WordPress site i have a custom post type of stories so i need the postmeta data to be merged into the posts table.

Is it possible to merge the 2 tables i understand there is a large amount of data inside of the postmeta table.

Comment: Hint: JOIN https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Theoretically it is possible, but horroble solution. You can move all wp_posts columns to wp_postmeta table as meta_key-meta_value couples. F.e. meta_key = post_title, meta_value = "my post title"